# How to retain the ASP.NET dropdownlist selected item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to retain the selected value of a dropdownlist once the user change the dropdownlist item but its not working as expected what I wanted is to retain the selected item in the dropdownlist but its it defaulted to the `Select Company` everytime i select the item from dropdownlist, once the user change it postback the page (i know there is no postback in the MVC)

What I'm doing wrong here?

```
<div class="form-group">
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "form_dropdown" }))
   {
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ListOfCompanies, 
      new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)Model.ListOfCompanies, "Value", "Text"), 
      "Select Company", new { @class = "form-control", Name = "sel" })
  }
```

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string sel)
{
   var vModel = new EmployeeViewModel();
   vModel = _db.GetEmployee.ToList();

   //load list of companies:

   var company =   _db.LoadComapny.ToList();          
   IEnumerable<SelectListItem> result = model.Select(b => new SelectListItem
   {
       Value = b.Value,
       Text = b.Text,
       Selected = b.Text == sel
   }).ToList(); 

   vModel.ListOfCompanies = company;
   vModel.SELECTED_COMPANY = sel;

   return View(vModel);
}
```

Model:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListOfCompanies { get; set; }
   public string SELECTED_COMPANY { get; set; }
   //other props
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`DropdownListFor`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) has 2 important argumnets:

1. the first one the variable with the index of the selected item (mostly lambda expressions (**`=>`**) were used)
2. the secound one is the [**`SelectList`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx) of items availble

   ```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SELECTED_COMPANY, 
       new SelectList(Model.ListOfCompanies, "Value", "Text"), 
       "Select Company", new { @class = "form-control", Name = "sel" })
   ```

Comment: 1 + Thanks for explanation this was driving me crazy

Comment: Since property `ListOfCompanies` is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` is just pointless extra overhead to create a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from it. It just needs to be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SELECTED_COMPANY, Model.ListOfCompanies, "Select Company", ...)`

Answer (score 1):

Update it to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SELECTED_COMPANY, 
      new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)Model.ListOfCompanies, "Value", "Text"), 
      "Select Company", new { @class = "form-control", Name = "sel" })
```